# How do I delete a route from Linux routing table

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ip-routing

This turns out to be harder than I thought.  The routes I want to delete are the "!" rejected routes, but I can't seem to formulate the right "route del" command to pull it off.

Here is the routing table...

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
67.40.227.206   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.46.79   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ipsec0
192.168.46.79   -               255.255.255.255 !H    2      -        0 -
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 ipsec0
10.1.0.0        -               255.255.0.0     !     2      -        0 -
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     3      0        0 ppp0
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     4      0        0 ppp0
```

I have two entries for 192.168.46.79 and 10.1.0.0.  These are auto-generated by the little Linux based router I'm using.  I can ping the IPSEC tunnels from the shell itself, but traffic from the LAN takes the second route (the rejected "!" or "!H" route) for reasons I simply don't understand.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say traffic takes the 'second route'?

Comment: Notice the two table entries for 192.168.46.79?  At the router shell, if I ping that side of the tunnel it works.  From the LAN-side, traffic goes to the "second 192.168.46.79" entry and is rejected/drops.

Comment: I also don't understand why the SG560 generates two (2) table entries for "default" and the IPSEC destinations.  I'm perplexed.

Answer (score 100):

with the `route -n` command you'll obtain

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         160.98.123.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
```

`sudo route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.178.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth0`

you'll get all parameters respectively from above

Comment: After reboot, it again comes . How can I delete permanently ?

Comment: @shyamkkhadka it depends from which process it has been created... recommend you to post a question with your specific case to analyze it. Give details about the route you got and want to remove. Mostly the dhcp server and client will create the routes

Comment: what if the gateway is `-` ?

Comment: Is there a delete-everything command? docker has created so many and I can't be bothered typing this in every time I need to use the internet (it conflicts with vpns, lans, everything).

Comment: @jozxyqk not that I know of, you'd have to awk the result of the `route -n` and play with that into a `while read line`. That's how I'd do that.

Answer (score 19):

The types of the routes with the `!` flag are either unreachable or prohibit.  `route`, being an ancient utility from net-tools, does not differentiate between the two.  Use iproute2.

The net-tools way to delete these routes would be to use `route del` on it.  However, net-tools provides no way to differentiate between the rejected route and the other one (because the dev argument is optional, though not specifying a device is likely to remove the unreachable route).

iproute2 allows you to do it like this:

```
ip route del unreachable 10.1.0.0/24
ip route del unreachable 192.168.46.79/32
```

It might not be unreachable, but prohibit.  Use `ip route` with no arguments to determine which.

Answer (score 12):

I think it's this: `route del -net 10.1.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 metric 2`

I'm not 100% certain.  But, I think you've got something else goofy going on since you have 2 default routes.

Comment: +1 : 2 default routes is always a sign of something being misconfigured (unless they actually point to different gateways and have different metrics).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience,

```
route del -host <ip> reject
```

should work. In your specific case,

```
route del -host 192.168.46.79 reject
```

should do the trick. Please note that this applies to routes I manually added. I'm not entirely certain why yours has duplicate routes without interfaces. As such, it may be necessary to apply a metric parameter, as described by baumgart.

Answer (score 0):

All the time someone try to hack me and i afraid to be bridged. I use VPN and adress  84.17.53.166 is from it.
Is that route ok?

pek@pop-os:~$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         10.8.8.1        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0

0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enx001e101f0000

10.8.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun0

84.17.53.166   192.168.8.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   50     0        0 enx001e101f0000

169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx001e101f0000

192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx001e101f0000

192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 enx001e101f0000

Answer (score -2):

Please see if there is a "device config file" under /etc/network/interfaces.d/
-> I had eht0!! Really, it was eht0 and not eth0 there!

Comment: You might want to expand your answer somewhat, as it is not obvious at present how it relates to the question being asked.